# Python Pandas: Got an Error from trying to bin data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bin

Python is returning this error message. Would anyone happen to know how to fix?

```
 TypeError: putmask() argument 1 must be numpy.ndarray, not numpy.int64
```

I got this error when trying to use pd.cut to classify my data into different bins, as seen below:

```
df['Credit Score'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['Credit Score'] = df['Credit Score'].astype(int)
bins = [0, 500, 550, 600, 650]
Summary_Scores = df.groupby(pd.cut('Credit Score', bins))
```

The data is being read from a csv file:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5729 entries, 0 to 252032
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Loan #          5729 non-null int64
Amount          5729 non-null float64
Issue Date      5729 non-null datetime64[ns]
Purposes        5661 non-null object
Credit Score    5729 non-null int32
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int32(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 246.2+ KB
None
```

Comment: Can you share enough data to reproduce the error?

Comment: It looks like the first argument to `pd.cut` shouldn't be a string: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html

Comment: Hello Ian, the data is being read from a csv file.

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Credit Score'], bins))` should be the correct syntax. You need to pass an array like sequence as `pd.cut`'s input.

Comment: Excellent! It worked - thanks so much Nickil!